# Html video playlist

Tags: jquery, video, playlist

I have a video player on my page which plays the video accordingly to which link was pressed.

I am trying to create this so that it will also be able to skip to a certain part of a video based on another button.

So far I have them both working on separate pages. 
Here is whatI have so far:

```
<div id="video-player"> 

       <img src="images/videoplayer/screen680.png" id="video-screen"/>    
      <video id="videoarea" poster="" src=""></video>

      <ul id="playlist">
        <li movieurl="video/1.Adele Gillies_short_compressed.mp4" id="myvideo">

            <button class="video-button left-menu"  id="education-jump">vid1 education</button>
            <button class="video-button left-menu" id="education-jump2">vid2 eductaion</button>
        </li>

        <li movieurl="video/1.William Morrison_short-comp.mp4" id="myvideo2">
            <button class="video-button left-menu"  id="relationship-jump">vid1 relationships</button>
            <button class="video-button left-menu" id="relationship-jump2">vid2 relationships</button>
        </li>


      </ul>
  </div> 

 <script> 
            var myvideo = document.getElementById("myvideo"),
            playbutton = document.getElementById('playme'),
            jumplink1 = document.getElementById('education-jump');
            jumplink2 = document.getElementById('education-jump2');


        jumplink1.addEventListener("click", function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            myvideo.play();
            myvideo.pause();
            myvideo.currentTime = 200;
            myvideo.play();
        }, false);

         jumplink2.addEventListener("click", function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            myvideo.play();
            myvideo.pause();
            myvideo.currentTime = 170.1;
            myvideo.play();
        }, false);





    </script>

<script type="text/javascript">
          $(function() {
    $("#playlist li").on("click", function() {
        $("#videoarea").attr({
            "src": $(this).attr("movieurl"),
            "poster": "",
            "autoplay": "autoplay"
        })
    })
    $("#videoarea").attr({
        "src": $("#playlist li").eq(0).attr("movieurl"),
        "poster": $("#playlist li").eq(0).attr("moviesposter")
    })
})
        </script>
```

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: How would I skip to a certain part of a video while still being able to play multiple videos  on the page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this attaches the event to the buttons (rather than the `<li>`) but still reads the URL from the parent group but sets a fake time attribute from the button used to trigger the load

to avoid too much flickering it also checks to see if the video is changing (in which case it does the whole reload) or if the video is the same, just a new position all it does is change the current time.

I think that's what you're after...

```
     <div id="video-player"> 

      <video id="videoarea" poster="" src="" proload="auto" controls></video>

      <ul id="playlist">
        <li movieurl="video.mp4" id="myvideo">
            <button class="video-button left-menu"  id="education-jump" time="20">vid1 education</button>
            <button class="video-button left-menu" id="education-jump2" time="30">vid2 eductaion</button>
        </li>

        <li movieurl="video2.mp4" id="myvideo2">
            <button class="video-button left-menu" id="relationship-jump" time="10">vid1 relationships</button>
            <button class="video-button left-menu" id="relationship-jump2" time="50">vid2 relationships</button>
        </li>

      </ul>
  </div> 

<script> 
    var myvideo = document.getElementById("videoarea")

    $(".video-button").on("click", function() {
        // if we need to load a new video do so
        if ($("#videoarea").attr("src") != $(this).parent().attr("movieurl")) {
            $("#videoarea").attr({
                "src": $(this).parent().attr("movieurl"),
                "poster": "",
                // load a fake attribute with the desired start time
                "starttime": $(this).attr("time")})
            $("#videoarea").on("canplay",function() {
                // set the current time to the fake attribute
                myvideo.currentTime=$(this).attr("starttime")
                myvideo.play();
                // remove the event to stop it triggering multiple times
                $("#videoarea").off("canplay")
            })
        } else {
            // if the video URL didn't change, just adjust the time
            myvideo.currentTime=$(this).attr("time")
        }
    })

 </script>
```

Comment: My pleasure. Hopefully it makes sense and you can extend it as needed.

Comment: Just a quick little question, would it be possible to pause or stop the video at a certai time for each part?

Comment: I'd have a quick look at my answer here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15435976/video-event-on-given-second/15446252#15446252 ... the code in that sample shows how to use the `timeupdated` event to react at certain points

Comment: Cool, that seems to be good. I was just wondering how I would specify different file types in the <li> because i need to addan .ogv version in there to

Comment: if file names are the same, I would strip off the .mp4 from the <li mediaurl="video1"> then when you add the source add one for video1.mp4 and one for video1.ogv, or use the canPlayType method to determine which you should use

Comment: Yes the file names are the same, I'm a little bit confused by this? So would i add in video1.mp4, video1.ogv into the source which is currently blank and retrieving the data from the <li movieurl="video1.mp4">?

Comment: have a look at this modified version of the answer - http://jsfiddle.net/FBzwq/ it detects if the browser supports .mp4 and if not falls back to the .ogg version (could add in detection for WebM as well by testing for `video/webm; codecs="vp8, vorbis"`

Comment: Perfect. Thanks so much for all your help. My video player is nearly complete

Comment: awesome :) Hope it does everything you need

Comment: Is it possible to fall back onto both an .ogg and .webm? I have tried to write another else statement but that seemed to have broken the script.

Comment: I updated the fiddle to fall back from mp4 to webm to ogg (in that order). if you're still having an issue can you post something I can have a look at?

Comment: ok, I just wasn't sure because i didn't have see the file type in the script. Any way heres a link to the video player http://www.pcmoceania.com/library/testimonials/ if you click the testimonials button in the tv it will pop up. For some reason I can't get the video to show on chrome for windows and IE the video plays sound and shows in the controls that it's playing. Everything else works fine. Any ideas on this

Comment: the file type (eg .mp4 or .webm) gets added in line 8/10/12 of the updated Fiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/FBzwq/4/. I had a look in IE9 and Chrome on Win8 and videos play fine, what versions of OS/Browser are you having problems with (and as a Northern Beaches boy at heart it was great to hear Aussie accents over here in the US!)